# Integrating wordpress into existing site and setting up htaccess?

Tags: permalinks

I have a question, I was hoping you could possibly help me out, that would be awesome!

My primary site is NOT wordpress in my root directory and all pages. I have wordpress installed in the folder /blog. My primary site is just normal, I use wordpress in a folder for tech articles.

In google webmaster tools, google is finding links it should not be. For example I have a page http://www.example.com/about.php which is correct. Google will find that page and it also finds http://www.example.com/blog/about.php – that page returns a 404 error of course, but my question is why is it doing that? In my wordpress theme I have a menu with site links, etc. Like About Us So in the /blog folder somehow wordpress is making google think that it is /blog/about.php which does not actually exist. Make sense? Is is something in .htaccess to change in my blog folder? If so, how do I fix it? Thanks so much.

Comment: Please provide your .htaccess CODE, that will help solving the issue.

Comment: There are 2 .htaccess files. One is in the root, that is for my whole site. Then when I installed wordpress in /blog it has its own .htaccess file. I haven't modified it. This is the default in the /blog folder...

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress